# Firefox is unusable after Ubuntu 14.04 update process

Tags: certification

After daily package update firefox is unnable to connect to any https server, like www.google.com, ubuntu.com and so on. To ask this question I  needed to install konqueror to be able to enter https web site. No matter what certificate files I've added - no change: error on certification for any https connection and firefox is completely unusable.

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`? Also try `sudo apt-get purge firefox` and `sudo apt-get install firefox`.

Comment: I did it as first option and it didn't help. Moved to QupZilla browser which can hendle all issues with certifications.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to check that your system's date and time are accurate.  This can cause issues when validating certificates and have them show up as invalid.

Comment: The date and time are accurate. It is not the problem.